# Rango de fechas: this field cannot hold more than 1 values when I try to sync content to a node with a date range field

Tags: datetime, feeds, 10

I'm working with Feeds to sync content from a JsonAPI resource.

Everything works fine except the date range field.

I get dates like this from the source:

```json
 0 => "2023-10-27T00:00:00"
 1 => "2023-10-28T00:00:00"
 2 => "2023-10-29T00:00:00"
```

And I have try to return:

```php
return 
  [
   'value' => reset($source_data),
   'end_value' => end($source_data),
  ];
```

Also

```php
return reset($source_data).'/'.end($source_data);
```

But i get always the same error.

This is my mapper configuration:

[image]